# Write Fortran-like format to file in Python

Tags: python, fortran

In Fortran, I can use:

```
open(10, file = 'output')
write(10, '(5A10)') 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', 'berry'
```

Is there a similar way in Python of writing the output?

I know I can use:

```
f.write('%5s\t%5s\t%5s\t%5s\t%5s' % ('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', 'berry'))
```

But how can I make it more compact? Using a similar way of `'(5A10)'`, instead of the lengthy `'%5s\t%5s\t%5s\t%5s\t%5s'`.

Comment: You can try storing it as a tuple, say t, and use f.write(*t).

Comment: It's not just Fortran 90 where you can do this ... This formatting goes back to at least Fortran 77.  I never really dug into the F66 standard well enough to know whether you could do it portably there...

Comment: note modern fortran supports a variable multiplier: `write(10,'(*(a10))')` so you don't need to hard code the list length.  I don't think there is a nice way to do that in python.

Comment: @agentp: Great tip! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot! I should ask more questions in Stack Overflow. People here are like genius! Lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no real shortcut here.  In this case, you might try:

```
file_handle.write('\t'.join('%s' % f for f in fruits))
```

I'm not sure that this ends up being much more compact until fruits gets a little longer, but I think that it does make the output a little more obvious...

Also, if I'm reading your format statement correctly (it's been 2 years since I've spend much time with Fortran), you are formatting 5 strings with each 10 characters wide.  The corresponding python format code for a string that is 10 characters wide is `'%10.10s'`  (10 characters minimum, 10 characters maximum width).  In that case, the tabs are unnecessary and you could write it as:

```
>>> fruits = ('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', 'berry')
>>> (5*'%10.10s') % fruits
'     apple    banana    orange     grape     berry'
```

Which isn't *too* much more verbose than the fortran way.

Comment: OK. Because the data I am dealing with has a varying column. The fortran format writing is more easier to deal with. I will use `f.write('%s' % ('apple\tbanana\torange\tgrape\tberry'))` for now. But I just learnt a new way of writing output in Python from you. Already keep a note for this :)

Comment: @JianliCheng -- `'%s' % 'some_string'` is the same thing as `some_string`.  No need to do formatting in that case :-)

Comment: The `5*'%10.10s'` trick is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much. But what if some elements in my array are integers or floats? In fortran, I can do `'(2A4, 3I4)'`, which write 2 strings with 4 characters and 3 integers with 4 characters.

Comment: `'2 * '%4.4s' + 3 * '%4.4d'` is one option.  This will 0-pad the integers.  If you don't want them 0-padded (as I don't think they will be in fortran with that format statement), then you could just do `5 * '%4.4s'` as the format statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can use fortranformat:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortranformat

Works great!

```
>>> import fortranformat as ff
>>> header_line = ff.FortranRecordWriter('(A15, A15, A15)')
>>> header_line.write(['x', 'y', 'z'])
  '              x              y              z'
>>> line = FortranRecordWriter('(3F15.3)')
>>> line.write([1.0, 0.0, 0.5])
  '          1.000          0.000          0.500'
>>> line.write([1.1, 0.1, 0.6])
  '          1.100          0.100          0.600'
```